# Trouble with Dagger2 scoping Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, dagger-2

I am having trouble scoping a "child" Fragment to another Fragment's module with Dagger2.

Example Code:

```
@Module
abstract class SampleParentModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SampleChildModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeParentFragment(): ParentFragment
}

@Module
abstract class SampleChildModule {

    @ChildFragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeChildFragment(): ChildFragment
}
```

Everything compiles fine, then when running i get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class <\ChildFragment>

Here is my `FragmentScoped` and `ChildFragmentScoped` annotations.

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.CLASS,
    AnnotationTarget.FILE,
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
annotation class FragmentScoped

@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.CLASS,
    AnnotationTarget.FILE,
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
annotation class ChildFragmentScoped
```

If I replace the `ChildFragmentScoped` annotation in the `SampleChildModule` with a `FragmentScoped`, then add `SampleChildModule` to the `SampleParentModule` likeso: `@Module(includes = [SampleChildModule::class])` that works.  But it's not what I'm looking to do, I only want the child module available to the one fragment.

The `SampleParentModule` is used in an `ActivityBindingModule` for the activity, likeso:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SampleParentModule::class])
    abstract fun sampleActivity(): SampleActivity
}
```

Which then gets added to the `modules` array of the main `AppComponent`.

The fragments extend `DaggerFragment` and the activity extends `DaggerAppCompatActivity`.

Comment: It happens often because fragment is not open

Comment: I guess you're using `AndroidInjection` here? Does your parent fragment [implement `HasFragmentInjector`](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.java#L105)?

Comment: Why `internal`? Also where is `SampleParentModule` used?

Comment: I've updated my post.  `internal` was added by mistake, the real code doesn't have it.